# Angular module.run method being called for every unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Folks

I have a jasmine-karma unit test setup for my angular app. The issue is in my app.js defined module.ru, this method is calling a custom service (LoginService) that in turns calls a $http service. The issue I'm having here is, I am testing my LoginService and mocking the $http service, when I try to flush, it throws error:

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET /frontend/login
 No more request expected
```

I believe this extra request is coming from the module.run.

```
 app.run(['LoginService',function(LoginService){

     LoginService.checkLoginStatus().then(function(status){
         console.log(status);

       }, function(status){

           console.log(false);

      });

}]);
```

This is my plunkr code: http://plnkr.co/edit/f9bEH1fNTxDoxvWfajH5

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem. My module.run method to load a config file isn't running at all.

Comment: @N13 are you running an e2e test? Are you bootstrapping the main module?

Comment: It is no longer an issue. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that, in my unit test, I was bootstrapping the entire app

```
 beforeEach(module("app")).
```

Once I segmented my controllers, directives and services into their own module

```
 beforeEach(module("app.controllers"))
 beforeEach(module("app.directives"))
 beforeEach(module("app.services"))
```

Then I no longer faced the issue. The test I had configured wasn't unit testing but, was e2e testing.